# App restarts phone (unintentionally)

Tags: android

In the latest update of my Android app, customers are complaining that the app startup sometimes restarts (!) the phone. This is the first time I hear about something like that; I get regular crashes, but crashing Android itself?

Compared to the previous version, the new nontrivial modes of interacting with the system that kick in at app startup are:

Detecting shake events:

```
m_Sens = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
//...
m_Sens.registerListener(m_OnShake, m_Sens.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Announcing a network service via NSD:

```
NsdServiceInfo si = new NsdServiceInfo();
si.setServiceType(Type);
si.setServiceName(Name);
si.setPort(Port);
NsdManager Mgr = (NsdManager)c.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
NsdReg Reg = new NsdReg(Mgr);
Mgr.registerService(si, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, Reg);
```

I've got two customers who are complaining. One has Highscreen Alpha GTR with Android 4.1.2. The other has something called "Fly".

Any idea, please, what kind of app fault would make the phone reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug in NSD:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35585
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39750

With this in mind, going back to JmDNS (where it works, which is below Android v5) looks like the only viable option.